# Use RadioButton in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use RadioButton in Xamarin forms:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Prototype.Views.SetupGender">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Im a"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

            <RadioButton Text="Male" />
            <RadioButton Text="Female"/>
            <Button Text="Next" WidthRequest="100" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#0077BE" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The cs-file:

```
public SetupGender()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}


void OnGenderChange(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Value)
    {
        // Is checked
        
    }
}

private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The class, property, or method you
> are attempting to use ('RadioButton') is part of RadioButton; to use
> it, you must opt-in by calling
> Forms.SetFlags("RadioButton_Experimental") before calling
> Forms.Init().'

What can I try to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

before XF5.0 RadioButton was an experimental feature, and to use it you have to do **exactly what the error message says**, set the [experimental flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/internals/experimental-flags) before you call `Init`

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("RadioButton_Experimental");
```

Answer (score 2):

Jason's answer is correct, but you can implement the following fix in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        Device.SetFlags(new[] { "RadioButton_Experimental" });
        InitializeComponent();
        // ...
    }
```